# MySQL insert inside foreach only being called once

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array `$alert_note`. I iterate through a loop and fill it up with a few strings:

```
$n = 0;
$alert_note = array();
$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

    //some code in here populates the $results[$n] array with results from $row

    $thisnote = "<b>Location alert</b><br>
    Alert ID: {$results[$n]['alert-id']}<br>
    Start: {$results[$n]['start-formatted']}<br>
    End: {$results[$n]['end-formatted']}<br>
    Radius: {$results[$n]['radius-km']} km<br>
    Distance: {$results[$n]['distance-km']} km<br>
    <ul>\n";
    //$results[$n]['data'] is a nested array, so iterate through it:
    foreach($results[$n]['data'] as $name => $data){
        $thisnote .= "<li>$name: $data</li>\n";
    }
    $thisnote .= "</ul>";
    $alert_note[$n] = $thisnote;

    $n++;
}
```

Then I call a `foreach` function:

```
foreach($alert_note as $alert_note_contents){
    error_log("Note: $alert_note_contents");
    mysqli_query($dblink, "INSERT INTO `incident_events` (`incident`, `data`, `time`, `operator`) VALUES ('$incident', '$alert_note_contents', '$now', '$operator')");
}
```

Each string in `$alert_note` shows up as expected in the PHP error log, but only the last one is inserted into the MySQL table. No PHP errors are being thrown. Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: Place an  or die ('Unable to execute query. '. mysqli_error($dblink)); in your mysqli_query and lets see if there is an sql error.

Comment: Just tried that, and got an error caused by an unescaped quote. Added a `mysqli_real_escape_string` and now everything's working. Thanks for the prod in the right direction!

Comment: I'm glad for that I've helped you!

Answer (score -1):

plz before foreach($alert_note as $alert_note_contents){

do this so i can get the error 
var_dump($alert_note );
and do this plz so i can see if there is any error ind db

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 // Check connection 
if ($conn->connect_error) 
{ die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } 

$sql = "INSERT INTO incident_events (incident, data, time, operator) VALUES ('$incident', '$alert_note_contents', '$now', '$operator')";
 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
{ echo "New record created successfully"; } 
else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; }
 $conn->close();
```